# Stream to JSON file using yield

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a function that read a file that reads chunks and return the following after every iteration.

```
def foo_now():
    for file in all_files:
        key_id, final_text = readChunk(file)
        yield {
            key_id : {
                'desc': final_text
            }
        }
```

Ealier I was storing all these returned dictionaries into one single dictionary and them dumping the whole dictionary into a JSON file using:

```
def foo_earlier():
    temp_dict = dict()
    for file in all_files:
        key_id, final_text = readChunk(file)
        temp_dict.update({key_id : {'desc': final_text}})
    return temp_dict

def saveJSON(filename, data):
    with open(filename, 'wb') as outfile:
        json.dump(data, outfile)
    print "Data saved in " + filename

saveJSON("file.json", foo_earlier())
```

But now I want to dump each dictionary one by one as it is read from the file using `foo_now()`. How should I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for item in foo_now():
    with open("my_out.json","ab") as f:
        json.dump(item,f)
```

or

```
with open("my_out.json","ab") as f:
    for item in foo_now():
        json.dump(item,f)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I am getting this error when I run that script `TypeError: <open file 'my_out.json', mode 'ab' at 0x0000000002B3FB70> is not JSON serializable` though the `print item` outputs the dictionary correctly!

Comment: whoops the arguments were backwards... fixed now